# Cannot find module express cors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ubuntu-20.04

I just clone my repository on my Ubunto 20.04 I have installed everything but I keep getting this error when I try to run the server. It works well on my windows machine.

> Error: Cannot find module '../../Middlewares/AllowCors' Require stack:
>
> - /home/medvik/Documents/github/nextjs-ecom/ecomApi/routes/User/CreateUser.js
> - /home/medvik/Documents/github/nextjs-ecom/ecomApi/app.js
> - /home/medvik/Documents/github/nextjs-ecom/ecomApi/bin/www
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>   at Object. (/home/medvik/Documents/github/nextjs-ecom/ecomApi/routes/User/CreateUser.js:4:19)
>   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
>   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

The core middleware file
path:/MiddleWare/AllowCors.js

```
const cors = require("cors");

const whitelist = [
  "http://localhost:8080", 
  "http://localhost:3000", 
];
var corsOptionsDelegate = (req, callback) => {
  var corsOptions;
  if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header("Origin")) !== -1) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true };
  } else {
    corsOptions = { origin: false };
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions);
};

exports.cors = cors();
exports.corsWithOptions = cors(corsOptionsDelegate);
```

My CreateUser file is in /router/User/CreateUser.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const joi = require("joi");
const allowCors = require("../../Middlewares/AllowCors");

router.route("/")
.options(allowCors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
}).post(allowCors.corsWithOptions, async (req, res) => {
  try {}} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the file system Linux is is case sensitive unlike windows
in my code, I had imported the cors middleware like this

```
const allowCors = require("../../Middlewares/AllowCors");
```

this works well in windows even tho the correct import should have been

```
const allowCors = require("../../MiddleWares/AllowCors");
```

since I named my middleware folder as MiddleWares.